# How to resolve, Gwt Compile error: refers to missing type "classname" in my playN project?

Tags: gwt, maven, compiler-errors, playn

I am getting a lot of gwt compile errors as follows in my playN project. Can anybody give me a hint about this? these are maven projects.

[
      Errors in 'jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.4.0/gwt-user-2.4.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/logging/server/RemoteLoggingServiceUtil.java'

```
     Line 69: The method logRecordFromJson(String) from the type JsonLogRecordServerUtil refers to the missing type JSONException

  Errors in 'jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.4.0/gwt-user-2.4.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/logging/server/StackTraceDeobfuscator.java'

     Line 53: No source code is available for type java.util.regex.Pattern; did you forget to inherit a required module?

     Line 60: No source code is available for type java.io.File; did you forget to inherit a required module?

     Line 176: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?

     Line 180: No source code is available for type java.io.FileInputStream; did you forget to inherit a required module?

     Line 206: No source code is available for type java.io.BufferedReader; did you forget to inherit a required module?

     Line 207: No source code is available for type java.io.InputStreamReader; did you forget to inherit a required module?

     Line 239: No source code is available for type java.util.regex.Matcher; did you forget to inherit a required module?

  Errors in 'jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.4.0/gwt-user-2.4.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/place/rebind/PlaceHistoryGeneratorContext.java'

     Line 196: The method format(String, String, String) is undefined for the type String

     Line 202: The method format(String, String, String, String) is undefined for the type String

     Line 212: The method format(String, String, String, String) is undefined for the type String

     Line 285: The method getCanonicalName() is undefined for the type Class<capture#2-of ? extends PlaceTokenizer<?>>

     Line 289: The method getSimpleName() is undefined for the type Class<WithTokenizers>

     Line 290: The method getCanonicalName() is undefined for the type Class<capture#4-of ? extends PlaceTokenizer<?>>
```

]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all package java.io is supported by GWT.

See [JRE Emulation Reference](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/RefJreEmulation.html) for details

It is no sense to emulate files/stream in browser.

Comment: but StackTraceDeobfuscator.java is not my class. its gwt's class right?

Comment: `com.google.gwt.logging.server.StackTraceDeobfuscator` - so it is not included to client code. All classes from package *.server are not included.

Comment: @Rockcollins yes it is. Did you by any chance use it in client-side code?

Comment: Can you detail a little more? I am a newbie in this.

Comment: I think it is not so easy. It open stream - you can not open stream in browser. GWT has a lot of limitations.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Java standard classes like `java.util.regex.Pattern`that are not enabled in GWT. See [the JRE-Emulation reference](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) for information on which standard classes are allowed for usage in GWT.

Edit: if this code is actually occuring in a plain server-side class, you GWT-module definition is wrong and includes server side code.

Comment: why it says , Errors in 'jar:file:/home/user/.m2/repository/com/google/gwt/gwt-user/2.4.0/gwt-user-2.4.0.jar!/com/google/gwt/logging/server/StackTraceDeobfuscator.java'. Isn't it a gwt's class?

Comment: You can find out if any of your client-side code imports or uses any class that is not supposed to be used on the client (e.g. it contains `server` in its package).

Comment: does that mean I am using StackTraceDeobfuscator in some of my client side classes?

Comment: I don't know, but it's possible. You might also use another class that uses `StackTraceDeobfuscator`. Do you use any GWT logging functionality?

Comment: No I am not using any logging functionality. I was using com.allen-sauer.gwt.log. I have removed it completely as I had this doubt.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using some unsupported Java classes.

But it was strange that I was not using it directly. I was inheriting a pure GWT project's classes which has the same package declarations of a standard Java project. So even though I was not using any Java classes which GWT doesn't support, it was compiling all the codes from my Java project too.

[solved] I just made the package names of these two projects different (the GWT project which I was inheriting and the standard Java project).

Seems that it will be helpful for others.